# Some Altair 3.0 charts are not displayed in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, altair

I tried to run Altair 3.0 in Google Colab but some charts are not rendered properly and the encodings are not shown.

I upgraded Altair to version 3.0 
`pip install --upgrade altair vega`

and applied the hack

`alt.display.colab_renderer.kwargs.update({'vega_version': '5', 'vegaembed_version': '4'})`

as described [here](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1464)

but it does show only the canvas.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.population.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot(extent='min-max').encode(
    x='age:O',
    y='people:Q'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The hack is no longer necessary; Colab currently supports Altair with no modification.

Choose *Runtime->Reset All Runtimes* to undo all the changes you have made to the altair installation, then run your code, and it should work:

```
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt

source = data.population.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot(extent='min-max').encode(
    x='age:O',
    y='people:Q'
)
```

[image]

Comment: just did as you suggested and now Altair 3.0.1 is imported but the sample chart is still not displayed.

Comment: Can you share a link to the notebook?

Comment: here it is https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qCO35sjnNVa2Ws1rGi_mwsPXPVRYJip3

Comment: The chart is there when I open the notebook. Is it possible that you have an ad-blocker on? That might be preventing the JS from loading the data from the URL when it renders the chart. If you open the javascript console, you should see an error indicating why the data is not being loaded.

Comment: Yes, I turned it off and now everything's working as expected. Thank you very much for the immediate response and support !